# How to bypass login for unit-testing Oracle APEX?

Tags: oracle-apex, cypress

According to the Cypress best practices, I should avoid using my login UI before each test. I'm struggling to do this using [Oracle APEX](https://apex.oracle.com/en) because it appears the login process requires a lot more than just username and password.

I have used chrome's `tamper data tool` and `Jmeter` to inspect the mechanics of the Oracle APEX login process and, essentially, the login process has 2 steps:
(1) the login page redirects to a login page with a valid session id in the URL, seeded with dozens of time-sensitive unique ids.
(2) Upon submitting your username and password, a POST request is made to /ords/wwv_flow.accept with the username, the password and several other time-sensitive unique identifiers.

It appears that APEX requires something similar to following for a successful login:

```
p_json : {"salt":"108222855956905007172773085768141257328","pageItems":{"itemsToSubmit":[{"n":"P101_USERNAME","v":"jsmith"},{"n":"P101_PASSWORD","v":"Password123"}],"protected":"unDCYO1qmj_OAwtyYNo_yA","rowVersion":""}},
p_flow_id : 4000250,
p_flow_step_id: 101,
p_instance: 6589106753596,
p_page_submission_id: 108222855…,
p_request : LOGIN,
p_reload_on_submit : A
```

All of these variables (besides the username and password) are available in the login page but to get them I'd have to visit the login UI, which is what I'm trying to avoid. Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the wrong approach. As for Unit testing you have to accept some degree of variability in terms of production vs. pre-production.
Saying the above I think you need to consider some more "normal" approach such as:

- Change passwords in Pre-Prod.
- Alternate Authentication Scheme.
- Alternate Build Option(s) based on your needs.

Comment: This makes sense to me. Thanks for recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about these best practices you mention, but the session information you might pass along you testing *must* be created by APEX engine on the server-side.

There is no such way to bypass the login by just passing some parameters to the server other than a proper credentials information. What you can do, however, is implementing a custom authentication schema in APEX that would authenticate (and would create your session) by using some token or some other custom way, for i.e., checking the browser agent, IP address, environment, I don't know.

This custom authentication schema isn't related to unit-testing though.